# How to order a list according to a property in the object whose list is a property in the object whose list I want to order?

Tags: c#

The title is not very clear. I'll try to explain my problem with code:

I have two classes A and B:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
}
```

and now I have a list of objects of type A and I want to order them, by the DateTime of their Bs. I thought I could do something like this:

```
private void MyFunc(List<A> As)
{
    var orderedAs = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.DT));
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue
Thanks

Comment: HI, 
you have many `DateTime` for every `A` ... So what exactly you want to sort them after? By Minimum Datetime, or Maximum, or maybe the average Datetime?

Comment: Thanks, I thought they'll be sorted in ascending order, but I don't really care whether it's ascending or descending. I just need the As to be sorted accordingly

Comment: Well I think this is not how it works - Let me explain this: Your code is selecting all Datetimes in your `List<B>` . So you have something like {"01.01.2016...",01.05.2018",...01.01.1990"} and  {"01.01.1016...",01.05.2001",...01.01.1999"}. How should those both lists be "ordered" (A's will be after their order)? You have to get an average of them, or maybe the Minimum value or something like this.

Comment: You will see this, if you add `.ToList()` to your `OrderBy(..` statement, You will get an error: `Minimum of object seeds to inheritate IComparable`, that isn't the case for `List<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you didn't told us what you want to order after so here are some suggestions:

```
var orderedByMax = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Max(b => b.DT));
var orderedByMin = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Min(b => b.DT));
var orderedByAverage = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Average(b => b.DT.Ticks));
var orderedByAmountOfB = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Count());
var orderedByFirstDTinListofB = As.OrderBy(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.DT).First());
```

Comment: I just checked it on my real application. The "Min" version is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @golan You're welcome - I added another comment to explain why your code wasn't working under your original question - maybe suggest marking as solution, so the question can be closed.